# How to update a record after extracting

Tags: java, hibernate

```
private List<String> getSCFData(int trdCustomerKy, Date lastRunDate, Date currentDate) throws TradeException {
    List<String> reportData = null;
    String paymentDate = EMPTY_STRING;
    String partyId = EMPTY_STRING;

    YOWDAO hdDAO = new YOWDAO(mConnection);
    List<YOWSCFExtractData> reportItems = hdDAO.getSCFData(trdCustomerKy, lastRunDate, currentDate);
    if (null != reportItems && reportItems.size() > 0) {
        reportData = new ArrayList<String>();
        mTracer.log("Total records retrieved: " + reportItems.size());
        for (YOWSCFExtractData data : reportItems) {
            String Source = (null != data.getSource()) ? data.getSource() : BLANK_STRING;

            String paymentCurrencyCd = (null != data.getPaymentCurrencyCd()) ? data.getPaymentCurrencyCd()
                    : BLANK_STRING;

            String sellerName = (null != data.getSellerName()) ? data.getSellerName() : BLANK_STRING;

            String paymentAmount = (null != data.getPaymentAmount()) ? data.getPaymentAmount() : BLANK_STRING;

            if (null != data.getPaymentDate()) {
                paymentDate = DateUtil.formatDate(data.getPaymentDate());
            }
            if (null != data.getapplCifId()) {
                partyId = hdDAO.getPartyId(mConfiguration.getCustomerKy(), data.getapplCifId());
            }

            String dataRow = StringUtils.join(new String[] { Source, data.getBankRef(), partyId, sellerName,
                    data.getPartyId(), paymentAmount, paymentDate, paymentCurrencyCd}, COMMA);
            reportData.add(dataRow);
        }
    }
    return reportData;
}
```

I am extracting the data from oracle database. I want to update the record of a column once it is fetched to a string. for example when I had extracted data.getBanref() then I want to set it some string back in database. how would I do that? I am using hibernate........

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set the object data whatever values you want and then save it in the hibernate. If you want to update then use `session.saveOrUpdate()` or if you want to save a new record then use `session.save()`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a hibernate query 
Update table_Name column_Name and set it to whatever you want and call this query in your program. It will be easier i think so